# Tradução para excesso de tags um pouco sem sentido

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Ao colocar uma pergunta, estava entusiasmado e coloquei seis tags. Pouco segundos após a sexta tag, o sistema alertou-me com a seguinte mensagem:

[image: Captura de Tela SOPT]

A tradução parece *à-lá-google-translator* (sem ofensa a quem traduziu):

[image: Captura de Tela SOEN]

Comment: @bfavaretto Hmm.. tens link para essa no METÃO? Sempre vou lá chatear...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93041/167534

Comment: @bfavaretto Interessante, e então? Desapareceu já da tua _inbox_ ou ainda para por ai?

Comment: Ainda aparece... E diz "1 hora atrás"

Comment: Resolvido com a primeira sugestão do @bfavaretto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ainda bem que não foi o Google Translate, pois ele consegue ser ainda pior, inclusive invertendo o sentido de *no more than*:

> Por favor, indique mais de 5 marcas

Minha sugestão:

> **Não utilize mais de 5 tags**

ou

> **Você só pode usar até 5 tags**

<sup>Esta é a segunda opção para não desagradar os portugueses, como o autor desta pergunta :)</sup>

Comment: Estás muito bem ensinado :P